# google-diff-match-patch - wrong word diff

Tags: java, google-diff-match-patch

I have 2 words "50g" and "75g" and using DiffMatchPatch showing that "5" and "g" is identical. Its suppose only "g" is identical.

This url you can test above words and it show the same result.
https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/demos/diff.html

[image]

Is it bug or i just had a wrong interpret about this?

Comment: Who says 5 is not identical?

Comment: @shmosel have you tried the link above and test? explain to me the result.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what you're confused about.

Comment: @shmosel i just update my post include the image. why 5 and g is not highlighted? is identical both words right? supposely only g is identical?

Comment: Yes, they're both identical.

Comment: @shmosel so explain to me why 5 is not highlight.. its suppose to highlighted because its different.. like 7 and 0...

Comment: Because they're not different. They both say "5g", with some additional letters interspersed.